# Codeigniter 3 : 404 page error, .htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

It may old and regular query about Codeigniter + 404 page error. I have tried answered from previous stackoverflow questions about this. But, I couldn't solve my problem.
I have copied Codeigniter project from another system (Ubuntu OS 64 bit) to Ubuntus OS system. But, I am getting 404 page as default.If I give `http://localhost/project/index.php/admin/login` its working but not `http://localhost/project/admin/login` or `http://localhost/project`.
Here are my configuration:
**config.php**

```
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/html/project';

    $config['modules_locations'] = array(
        APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',
    );
    $config['index_page'] = '';
    $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

And my **.htaccess** file:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule> 
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have tried `a2enmod rewrite` too

Comment: did you restart server  ?

Comment: Configure using vhost, setup a local domain using hosts file and try once. Then keep the base url blank.

Answer (score 1):

Check if mod rewrite is on.
If you are using apache2:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I mentioned it in my question

Comment: Something is wrong with mod rewrite. Can you post your vhost conf?

Comment: Ohhh your base url. You are not using virtual host. Try to create one it's more simple then this.

Comment: Downloaded new codeigniter , created .htaccess file . Its working ,without index.php.

Answer (score 0):

try rewriting it like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Just to make sure, do all your controller and model file names have the first letter capitalized ?

Comment: I changed first letter to capital for controller and model file name. Nothing changed

Comment: is `mod_rewrite` turned on in apache?, make sure you restart as well.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` is an Apache module ,has nothing to do with php.ini and yes it is enabled.

Comment: What does this: `$config['modules_locations'] ` do?

Comment: user specific module structure